# Show that all but a finite number of the closed,almost disjoint cubes, will have volume (measure) $ < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $E$ is a given $\textbf{compact}$ set, and $\mathcal{O}_n$ is the open set $$ \mathcal{O}_n = \{x \mid d(x,E) < \frac{1}{n} \}$$

I want to show that $$m \left ( \mathcal{O}_1 \right ) < \infty$$

Since $\mathcal{O}_1$ is open, $\exists$ closed almost disjoint cubes such that $$ \mathcal{O}_1 = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} Q_j$$.

Then $$d( Q_j, E) <1, \hspace{2mm} \forall j$$

How do I show that all but a finite number of these $Q_j$ will have measure $< \epsilon$?

Comment: In general, $m(\mathcal{O}_1) < \infty$ does **not** have to hold. You have to impose some assumption on $E$.

Comment: @ggfgfg Why do you think the result is true? Have you tried it with $E=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we are talking about subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure, otherwise what is $m$?

Under the compactness assumption, the claim gets easy, because $\mathcal{O}_n$ is open (why?), hence measurable and $E \subset B_R (0)$ for some $R >0$ (because $E$ is compact, hence bounded). This implies $\mathcal{O}_n \subset B_{R + 1/n}(0)$, so that the measure is finite.